# Let the result no longer display GAC information

Tags: powershell, ironpython

I use the following code to run the ironpython code in powershell, but the result of the output always shows the GAC information. See the picture
[image]

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\IronPython.dll")
$py = [ironpython.hosting.python]::CreateEngine()
$py.Execute("print 'IronPython Engine loaded.'")
```

Is there any way to hide it? I don't want to display it every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pipe the first command to Out-Null:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\IronPython.dll") | Out-Null

$py = [ironpython.hosting.python]::CreateEngine() 
$py.Execute("print 'IronPython Engine loaded.'")
```

Which suppresses all output from the command.

[image]